# INR to USD currency conversion in android using current exchange rate?

Tags: android, paypal

I am integrating PayPal in my android application.

following is the PayPal payment method, it is accepting only USD. but my currency format is INR. So please help how can i convert my currency from INR to USD  using current rate?

```
 //Creating a paypalpayment
    PayPalPayment payment = new PayPalPayment(new BigDecimal(String.valueOf(paymentAmount)), "USD", "Simplified Coding Fee",
            PayPalPayment.PAYMENT_INTENT_SALE);
```

Comment: You can use any free real time conversion api. https://www.exchangerate-api.com/documentation or https://currencylayer.com/

Answer (score 1):

You can use exchange rate APIs available [here.](https://www.exchangerate-api.com/documentation) I am not sure how reliable it is but you can change your INR currency in USD using this api. After that, you can pass it in Paypal method function.

Hope, it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

There are many currency APIs that can give you a current `INR` to `USD` rate or conversion to calculate your currency to `USD`.

The problem is that PayPal will charge your user in `USD` and only then PayPal or the user's bank determins the `INR` amount actually charged to the user. Similarly, only when you pay out from PayPal, you will know exactly how much `INR` you get from the `USD` amount you earned on PayPal.

In that sense, it would be better to fix your price in `USD` and display to the User a calculated, approximate price in `INR` beforehand (but mention that it's only approximate).

For this, you can try any currency API. I would recommend [SWOP currency exchange rate API](https://swop.cx/), an easy to use, fast, reliable and transparent foreign exchange rate API offering GraphQL and REST endpoints.

Disclaimer: I'm one of the developers of SWOP